# Search into folder shortcuts?

Tags: windows, windows-explorer, windows-search

In Windows Explorer, I've created a folder that contains a list of shortcuts to other folders. For example:

[image: Folder with multiple shortcuts]

Is there any way to search for files and content in just those folders?

I was hoping to just use the Explorer search bar, but it doesn't seem to look into folder shortcuts.

Comment: AFAIK, Windows sees shortcuts as files (`.lnk`), because that is all a shortcut really is. It is a file that contains data pointing to another location. While Windows Search can go into sub folders, it cannot follow shortcuts.

Comment: I was hoping there might be an option to tell it to follow the shortcut... :(

Answer (score 1):

You can use Library which includes links to your folders to search all folder links included in your library
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Shortcuts are simply a normal file pointing to some item to open it so you can't recurse into them and search. You need to [create](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/symbolic-links) a [symlink](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symbolic_link) or [hardlink](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hard_link). For example if the folder you want to use for searching is `C:\Searching` then you can run this

```
mklink /j "C:\Searching\Util" "C:\Users\My\Util"
```

to create a symlink folder from `C:\Users\My\Util` to `C:\Searching\Util`

In PowerShell you can do like this

```powershell
New-Item -ItemType Junction -Path "C:\Searching\logs" -Target "C:\Users\logs" # or
ni "C:\Searching\websites" -i SymbolicLink -ta "C:\My\websites"
```

In both cases you need to run the console as administrator, or you'll have to [enable developer mode](https://blogs.windows.com/windowsdeveloper/2016/12/02/symlinks-windows-10/)

After that you can search freely in Explorer or in any command line tools because the folder appear just exactly as if they're in the new folder. Here's an example on my PC:

[image: search within junctions result]

See also

- [Creating hard and soft links using PowerShell](https://stackoverflow.com/q/894430/995714)
- [How can I create a symbolic link on Windows 10?](https://superuser.com/q/1020821/241386)