# How can I create a symbolic link on Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, symbolic-link

I was reading http://web.archive.org/web/20160820000804/https://www.dropboxwiki.com/tips-and-tricks/sync-game-saves-across-multiple-computers, and I know junction/mklink worked in Windows 7 as well, but it seems like the *junction* command has been retired in Windows 10.

What's the correct way to make symbolic links in Windows 10?

Comment: What’s wrong with `mklink`?

Comment: Anyone has good or bad info about junctions within (corporate) roaming profiles? (i.e.) trouble lurking...

Comment: The link is (effectively) broken: *"The Unofficial Dropbox Wiki is no longer available."*

Comment: @PeterMortensen Fi've edited to put webarchive of the link to have more context at that time.

Answer (score 176, accepted):

#### It seems like the junction command has been retired in Windows 10.

You can download [junction](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-gb/sysinternals/bb896768.aspx) from Windows SysInternals (which is part of Microsoft):

> Junction not only allows you to create NTFS junctions, it allows you to see if files or directories are actually reparse points. Reparse points are the mechanism on which NTFS junctions are based, and they are used by Windows' Remote Storage Service (RSS), as well as volume mount points.
>
> Please read [this Microsoft KB article](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/205524) for tips on using junctions.
>
> Note that Windows does not support junctions to directories on remote shares.

---

#### So how do I create junctions or directory symbolic links in Windows 10?

Download `junction` as instructed above.

Now you can use the following commands.

**Create a junction:**

```
junction "C:\Documents and Settings\UserName\My Documents\My Dropbox\My Games" "C:\Documents and Settings\UserName\My Documents\My Games"
```

**Create a directory symbolic link:**

```
mklink /D "C:\Documents and Settings\UserName\My Documents\My Dropbox\My Games" "C:\Documents and Settings\UserName\My Documents\My Games"
```

You can use either `mklink /j` or `junction` in Windows 10 to create junctions.

You can use `mklink /d` in Windows 10 to create directory symbolic links.

Notes:

- `junction` can also list junctions and determine if a file is a junction unlike `mklink`.
- `mklink` is an internal command only available within a `cmd` shell.
- By default Administrator privileges are required to create symbolic links.

  It can also be granted to other users. The security setting "Create symbolic links" can be granted at:

  ```
    Configuration\Windows Settings\Security Settings\Local Policies\User Rights Assignment\
  ```

---

#### Examples

Using mklink to create a directory symbolic link:

```
F:\test>mklink /d test-dir-sym-link test
symbolic link created for test-dir-sym-link <<===>> test
```

Using mklink to create a junction:

```
F:\test>mklink /j test-junction test
Junction created for test-junction <<===>> test
```

Using junction to create a junction:

```
F:\test>C:\apps\NirSoft\SysinternalsSuite\junction.exe test-junction test

Junction v1.06 - Windows junction creator and reparse point viewer
Copyright (C) 2000-2010 Mark Russinovich
Sysinternals - www.sysinternals.com

Created: F:\test\test-junction
Targetted at: F:\test\test
```

---

#### Further Reading

- [An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line](http://ss64.com/nt/) - An excellent reference for all things Windows cmd line related.
- [mklink](http://ss64.com/nt/mklink.html) - Create a symbolic link to a directory or a file, or create a hard file link or directory junction.

Comment: Is this different to `mklink /j`?

Comment: @Jonno As far as I know it is the same when creating junctions. `junction` will also list junctions unlike `mklink`

Comment: As far as I can tell, you cannot use `mklink` inside *PowerShell*, so you must use `cmd.exe`. Also, you have to run it as Administrator. But don't take my word for it. I've been using a Windows computer for only about 40 hours.

Comment: @BrunoBronosky Correct. That is because `mklink` is an internal command only available within a `cmd` shell. Note some `cmd` internal commands **have** been implemented in `PowerShell`, for example `dir`.

Comment: @BrunoBronosky By default Administrator privileges are required. It can also be granted to other users: The security setting 'Create symbolic links' can be granted at: Configuration\Windows Settings\Security Settings\Local Policies\User Rights Assignment\

Comment: @BrunoBronosky There are some PowerShell equivalent for `mklink`, see [Powershell Hard and Soft Links](http://stackoverflow.com/a/894651), for example.

Answer (score 85):

Open a PowerShell session as elevated administrator and type:

```
New-Item -ItemType SymbolicLink -Path E:\Data\MyGames -Target "C:\users\UserName\MyGames"
```

or using less verbose syntax:

```
ni E:\Data\MyGames -i SymbolicLink -ta "C:\users\UserName\MyGames"
```

Surely in 2016 and with Windows 10 you don't want to fiddle around with cmd commands or external downloads.

Windows 10 comes with PowerShell 5 which has builtin support for creating symbolic links.

Comment: Surely in 2016, I should not have to jump through hoops to create symlinks! Still one of windows biggest fails.

Comment: You're joking, right? I'd much rather do "mklink /d test-dir-sym-link test" than "New-Item -ItemType SymbolicLink -Path E:\Data\MyGames -Target "C:\users\UserName\MyGames". The super-verbose PowerShell syntax isn't really to my liking...

Comment: @JaimedelosHoyosM - using shorter PowerShell syntax you can use `ni test-dir-sym-link -i SymbolicLink -ta test`

Comment: Is there a way to create a SymbolicLink from the PowerShell like this without administrator privileges?

Comment: Is there a way to list the less verbose syntax using `Get-Help`? For instance how did you find `-ta` is for `-Target`

Comment: @scape - you can use the first few letters of a parameter name if they they uniquely   identify the paramter, e.g. `-i` are enough for `-ItemType` but `-t` is not enough because there are more than one parameter that start with `t`, so we need to use `-ta`

Comment: @cjsimon, Yes, normal user can create symbolic links, but they need to have a certain user right to do so, Search for: `SeCreateSymbolicLinkPrivilege`

Answer (score 24):

If you want a GUI Tool for making/editing  that symlinks use
http://schinagl.priv.at/nt/hardlinkshellext/linkshellextension.html

Link Shell Extension (LSE) provides for the creation of Hardlinks , Junctions , Volume Mountpoints , and Windows7/8's Symbolic Links, (herein referred to collectively as Links) a folder cloning process that utilises Hardlinks or Symbolic Links and a copy process taking care of Junctions, Symbolic Links, and Hardlinks. LSE, as its name implies is implemented as a Shell extension and is accessed from Windows Explorer, or similar file/folder managers.  The extension allows the user to select one or many files or folders, then using the mouse, complete the creation of the required Links - Hardlinks, Junctions or Symbolic Links or in the case of folders to create Clones consisting of Hard or Symbolic Links. LSE is supported on all Windows versions that support NTFS version 5.0 or later, including Windows XP64 and Windows7/8/10.  Hardlinks, Junctions and Symbolic Links are NOT supported on FAT file systems, and nor is the Cloning and Smart Copy process supported on FAT file systems.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

If you have Windows 10 build 14972 (December 2016) or higher:

https://blogs.windows.com/windowsdeveloper/2016/12/02/symlinks-windows-10

you can enable developer mode:

https://howtogeek.com/292914/what-is-developer-mode-in-windows-10

then use `mklink` without admin. Alternatively, PowerShell 6.2.0 (March 2019) or
higher allow Symlink without admin:

```
New-Item -ItemType SymbolicLink -Path new.txt -Target old.txt
```

Comment: Upvote. Though the PowerShell SymbolicLink solution repeats a highly-voted answer from 2016, it finally makes clear that the target means the old file which gets a SymLink in the new file.

Comment: "without admin" is correct except when using "/D" switch.

Answer (score 2):

There is an open-source tool called [SymlinkCreator](https://github.com/arnobpl/SymlinkCreator) that provides a minimal UI for drag-n-drop both files and folders to be symlinked. It can use both relative paths (if in the same drive) or absolute paths for symlinking. There is an option to retain the script used for symlinking.

[image]

Disclaimer: I am the author of SymlinkCreator. I created it for my personal use but then shared it with everyone.

Comment: Please do not post the same answer to multiple questions. If the same information really answers both questions, then one question (usually the newer one) should be closed as a duplicate of the other. You can indicate this by [voting to close it as a duplicate](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/close-questions) or, if you don't have enough reputation for that, [raise a flag](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/flag-posts) to indicate that it's a duplicate. Otherwise tailor your answer to this question and don't just paste the same answer in multiple places.

Answer (score -1):

## There isn't any need to install anything!

There exists a simple and open-source [<kbd>**`symlink_creator.bat`**</kbd>](https://puvox.software/blog/easiest-method-create-symlink-symbolic/)  file.

- **Drag & Drop** desired file/folder onto that file.
- It's open-source [(see instructions)](https://puvox.software/blog/easiest-method-create-symlink-symbolic/), so, just **Right click >Edit** on file to see its content (only several lines) yourself. No extra `.exe` or `.dll` files need to be installed.

### Batch File

```
::  ================================================================== ::
::  ========================  Puvox.Software  ======================== ::
::  ================================================================== ::
::  ============== Symlink Creator with Drag&Drop v1.3 =============== ::
::  This script makes a symlink of any files/folders  ( ) 
::  ================================================================== ::
::  ================================================================== ::

@echo off
setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion

if "%~1"=="" ( mshta "javascript:alert('You should drag desired files onto this');close();" && exit )

set /P inputed_target_dir= Path to folder, wherein the symlink will be created:
set inputed_target_dir=%inputed_target_dir%\
set type=0

for %%a in (%*) do  (

rem  in PARENTHESIS we use ! instead % for set-ed variables  (read more: https://superuser.com/a/78509/249349 )
set original_path=%%a
set original_path_quoted=!original_path!
rem  Make it quoted (if it's not already quoted)
set original_path_quoted|find """" >nul || set original_path_quoted="!original_path!"

set isDirectory=no
:: if directory
FOR %%i IN (!original_path_quoted!) DO IF EXIST %%~si\NUL (
    set isDirectory=yes
    for /D %%i in (!original_path_quoted!) do SET original_drive=%%~di
    for /D %%i in (!original_path_quoted!) do SET original_dir=!original_drive!%%~pi
    for /f "delims=" %%i in (!original_path_quoted!) do SET original_basename=%%~ni
)

:: if file
FOR %%i IN (!original_path_quoted!) DO IF NOT EXIST %%~si\NUL (
    set isDirectory=no
    for /f "delims=" %%i in (!original_path_quoted!) do SET original_drive=%%~di
    for /f "delims=" %%i in (!original_path_quoted!) do SET original_dir=!original_drive!%%~pi
    for /f "delims=" %%i in (!original_path_quoted!) do SET original_basenameWithExt=%%~nxi
)


for /D %%i in ("%inputed_target_dir%") do SET target_drive=%%~di
for /D %%i in ("%inputed_target_dir%") do SET target_dir=!target_drive!%%~pi
  
set isSameDrive=1
IF /I "!original_drive!"=="!target_drive!" (  set isSameDrive=2 )

:: if same ditectories, then use prefix name
set prefix=
IF /I "!original_dir!"=="!target_dir!" ( set prefix=_symlinked_ )

if !type! LSS 1 (
    rem ::   If same drives, then allow user to choose HARD method. Otherwise, only SOFT can be used
    set type=2

    rem ::   DONT USE   "!isSameDrive!"=="yes"  comaprison, as it has issue  
    if /i !isSameDrive! GTR 2 ( set /P type= Seems source and Destinaton drives are same, so you have an opportunity to create HARD-SYMLINK [press 1], otherwise press ENTER and the default SOFT-SYMLINK will be created : )
)

:: if directory
if !isDirectory!==yes (
    FOR %%i IN (!original_path_quoted!) DO IF EXIST %%~si\NUL (
        IF "!type!"=="1" ( 
          mklink /J "!target_dir!\!prefix!!original_basename!" !original_path_quoted!
        ) ELSE ( 
          mklink /D "!target_dir!\!prefix!!original_basename!" !original_path_quoted!
        )
    )
)

:: if file
if !isDirectory!==no (
    FOR %%i IN (!original_path_quoted!) DO IF NOT EXIST %%~si\NUL (
        IF "!type!"=="1" ( 
          mklink /H "!target_dir!\!prefix!!original_basenameWithExt!" !original_path_quoted!
        ) ELSE ( 
          mklink "!target_dir!\!prefix!!original_basenameWithExt!" !original_path_quoted!
        )
    )
)


)
:: FOR loop


:: mshta "javascript:alert('error: creating Hard-Symlink for different drives has failed');close();"
mshta "javascript:alert('Finished');close();"
endlocal
```

Comment: You should add in your answer how exactly this batch file works and what your association with it is. Batch files can be very destructive and running random ones from the internet goes against common sense.

Comment: The answer above has already had a moderator comment on it. I was mainly concerned with your answer because that website you linked looks somewhat sketchy, and the format of your answer triggered some red flags for me. I'm just being paranoid really.

Comment: unfortunately, it finishes with an error "syntax is incorrect"

Comment: @T.Todua .... I just edited to add the actual content of the batch file too in case the link breaks again, the logic itself is available.

Comment: Can you run Javascript straight from CMD, without using electron, Node or react Native curious about the line containing => mshta