# Move unpartitioned space from one to another disk in Windows

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive, partitioning

I left for the system 100 GB thinking that it's enough... I updated to Windows 10.

Installed some programs, mainly Visual Studio, Office, Corel Draw etc...

Now, I don't know how, but I am running out of free space on the system drive.

I installed the MiniTool Partition Wizard, but I am not sure is it's possible to  move a partition to another [image]

I tried to install, say, Visual Studio on another disk, but it seems to be impossible, it always installs the main files on the C drive...

**Edit:**

I merged the C partitions but the boot partition to obtain:

[image]

Comment: Since you mentioned you updated to Windows 10, have you checked if you have previous version of Windows that has yet to be removed? By default, Windows 10 keep old windows installation for 30 days. But you can have it cleaned up immediately. Other potential disk usage are virtual memory and hibernation. I don't use hibernation, so I use `powercfg /h off` to turn it off. You can also change the virtual memory to another disk. The above can easily free up 10+GB.

Comment: how do I remove the previous version of windows? is there a tool for that? I use the CCleaner

Comment: Use the built-in disk cleanup utility. Keep in mind that once you do that, you can't go back to previous installation without reinstalling from scratch.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot do this unless you use something like a virtual machine where you can build out a virtual disk drive. Some VM software will let you "combine" physical hard disks into a "virtual disk" that the virtual machine would recognize as a single physical device. I believe VMWare has a software solution for this, if you need something specific to look at.

You're looking at three separate physical disks in that picture. The total space available on disk 1 is 111GB, that's all you get. You could certainly shrink that C drive partition to get room for an other partition, but you can't physically add a chunk of one hard drive to another. If you used Disk Manager to shrink the partition, your existing partitions on disk 1 plus the un-allocated space can still only equal 111GB.

If I were to take a guess, I'd say it looks like you're running out of space on your C drive and are trying to solve that problem. Since what you're asking isn't really possible, you have two options:

1. Get a larger hard drive to hold your Windows installation
2. Clean out your C: drive and move anything that doesn't need to be there over to a different drive with more space. Tools like CCleaner and WinDirStat can help with this process. You can also replicate the Windows file system on another disk and instruct the system to place downloads and other files in there so they don't bloat your installation hard drive.

Comment: I updated the OP, you are right, I am running out of free space on the system drive... I already cleaned what I could, but the "Installer" folder takes a lot

Comment: Finally, I would like to switch the system to D: and the files from D to C disk, I don't know if it's possible with the MiniTool Partition

Comment: @Serge I would not recommend using Partition Wizard to merge partitions as the other respondent suggested. It's all the convoluted horror of RAID with less security than using a single hard drive. Regarding the "installer" folder, run the Windows "Disk Cleanup" utility to clear that out. As far as swapping the system drives, you can definitely clone your current C drive into a fresh partition on D and move the D data over to current C, but best practice is to back it all up and run a fresh install on drive D to ensure stability.

Answer (score 1):

It´s not easy to group non-contiguous NTFS partitions but you have tools to do it for you: [Partition Wizard](https://www.partitionwizard.com/resizepartition/how-to-extend-partition-to-non-contiguous-space.html)

Comment: thanks, I installed this soft, but I don't know if it's possible to increase the system disk size C from the free space on the D

Comment: I didn´t realized it was 2 different physical disks you wanted to share. You cannot link it like that but you can mount your disk 3 where ever you want. For example you can move your workspace directory to the disk3 and mount it to appear at the normal location you usually use it. It´s not a partition move but it will give you the same feeling

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you use symlinks or junction directories for your program files directory or downloads or any other folder that's taking a lot of space.

Please refer to this question and it's accepted answer.
[Link to question](https://superuser.com/questions/1020821/how-to-create-a-symbolic-link-on-windows-10)

For example, I have a VERY big iTunes library. It takes 120 Gb aproximately. Since my SSD has only 120 GB total to store OS and apps, I made a junction in the iTunes library directory pointing to my D: drive, which has 2TB available. iTunes does not even realize it's writing into another drive, which is the point of using junctions.

You can also make a RAID setup, but unfortunately, that should be done before installing your OS. It has a lot of disadvantages for you, since you only need more free space.

Answer (score 0):

You can't. You're trying to merge partitions across two physical drives. This is impossible. You can move your operating system (if you're very careful and make backups) using special utilities.

I can't detail it here, but I found an article you may be interested in [here](http://www.techradar.com/how-to/computing-components/storage/how-to-move-your-operating-system-to-another-hard-drive-1296831).