# Should I create a junction and symlink to a directory at the same time?

Tags: windows-10, ntfs, symbolic-link

**OS**: Windows 10 Home.

After reading [the difference between a directory junction and a symlink](https://superuser.com/a/343079/402107), it is clear, that these two things are different.

What is not clear after reading [How do I create junctions or directory symbolic links in Windows 10?](https://superuser.com/a/1020825/402107), is whether I should create both the junction and the symlink, here I am confused.

**Situation**:

We have a local computer, into which we are adding a second HDD and want to store one directory symlink and / or junction in it.

The original directory is:

```
C:\Records
```

The destination directory is:

```
E:\Records
```

But the application mustn't know it is actually writing to drive E:.

Therefore I came up with an idea of creating symlink / junction.

Disclaimer: I am Linux user, please don't ruin me for this question.

Comment: Several cautions:  1.  It's easy to forget exactly what you set, sometimes years later or if someone new is working on that PC, so leave a TEXT file in the root with notes.  2.  Deleting the "wrong way" CAN destroy the source or target in W-10.  (Forgot WHICH combination, but in W-10:  deleting target or source of junction or symlink, deletes both, depending on IF using CMD vs Explorer.)  3.  MKLinks are GONE when logged in as a different current user, (or when one of the major recent W-10 "Upgrades" were done for the current user.)  These are powerful and very useful, but misunderstood tools.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Should I create both the junction and the symlink?

No. You only need to create one of them, and in your particular usage case it doesn't matter which one.

See the diagram from https://superuser.com/a/1291446/337631:

[image]

---

#### Further Reading

- [An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line](http://ss64.com/nt/) - An excellent reference for all things Windows cmd line related.
- [mklink](http://ss64.com/nt/mklink.html) - Create a symbolic link to a directory or a file, or create a hard file link or directory junction.