# Win 10 MKLINK in C:\Users Access Denied

Tags: filesystems, windows-10

I have Win 10 21H2 Bld 19044.1706 stand-alone workstation, no domain, just WORKGROUP.

I did a Laplink PCMover transfer to new computer but it changed profile name from "john.WORKGROUP" to "john".  Everything is working except a million links like "C:\Users\john.WORKGROUP\Documents\something.exe" so I want to make a link named "C:\Users\john.WORKGROUP" that points to "C:\Users\john" but everything I've tried results in "Access Denied."

User "john" is an administrator.

I changed ownership of everything in Users to "jerry" (was "TrustedInstaller") and ran "Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName Microsoft-Windows-Subsystem-Linux" in powershell, rebooted, but still Access Denied.

How can I make this link?

(I know this is **server**fault, but StackOverflow does not seem like the right place and windows forums are useless.)

Comment: What exactly was the point of installing WSL?!?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I create a symbolic link on Windows 10?](https://superuser.com/questions/1020821/how-can-i-create-a-symbolic-link-on-windows-10)

Answer (score 0):

Open your command prompt using "Run as Administrator".

Comment: "John" is already an administrator and nothing happens when I click on CMD or PowerShell "Run as Administrator" but when I just click the icon it asks if I want to all app to change system, si I'm pretty sure I'm running with elevated privileges.